# How to get the exact message of form.errors?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get only the error message of the form. But there are special characters are shown with the message.

Here are my codes:

forms.py

```
class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...........

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FilterForm, self).clean()
        payee = cleaned_data.get("payee")
        memo = cleaned_data.get("memo")

        if not payee or not memo:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "You must put a value either for Payee or Memo")

        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
..............       

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FilterForm(request.user, request.POST, instance=filter)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "New rule created successfully")  
    else:
        messages.error(request, [v[0].__str__() for k, v in form.errors.items()])

...........
```

When I submit the invalid form. I get an output like this:

```
['You must put a value either for Payee or Memo']
```

How to get only the message without this `[' ']`?

```
//the error message is shown from here
messages.error(request, [v[0].__str__() for k, v in form.errors.items()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a list with the list comprehension expression `[v[0].__str__() for k,v in form.errors.items()]`, that's where you are getting the `[ ]`.

Here is a better way to do what you are trying:

```
errors = '<br />'.join('<br />'.join(i for i in form.errors.values()))
messages.error(request, errors)
```

Your form may raise multiple errors, which is why you need to loop and fetch each error item.  The standard practice is to pass the form back to the view, and then display the errors from the form object itself:

```
if form.is_valid():
     # do stuff
else:
   return render(request,{'form': form})
```

Then in your view:

```
{% if form.errors %}
   <strong>Please fix the errors</strong><br />
{% endif %}
<form>
   {% for field in form %}
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
   {% endfor %}
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I get this error `sequence item 0: expected string, ErrorList found`

Comment: Don't worry about fetching it inside the built-in messages because our template script can handle about that.